# Dot notation key extraction for deeply nested objects, arrays and arrays of objects

Tags: typescript, types, nested

I want to extract all deeply nested keys, including ones in arrays, but excluding intermediate index access:

```js
type Pack = {
  name: string
  items: string[]
}

interface Params {
  name: string
  items: string[]
  pack: Pack
  packs: Pack[]
  nested1: {
    nested2: {
      nested3: string
    }[]
  }
}

type ParamKeys = <...> // expected: 'name' | 'items' | 'pack' | 'pack.name' | 'pack.items'| 'packs' | 'packs.name' | 'packs.items' | 'nested1' | 'nested1.nested2'| 'nested1.nested2.nested3'
```

I know this has been somewhat answered multiple times, but all solutions require array indexes, e.g. `packs.8.name` because the key is inferred as `packs.${number}.name`. In my case I want the user to construct a record of options that will apply to all array elements, therefore the index is not really useful and excludes nested elements in the array as required keys which is not what I want. Another less ideal solution would be to have the index be explicitly typed to zero if the above is not feasible, i.e. `nested1.nested2.0.nested3` as a required key, for example

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NaRYBm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, it almost works, thank you. I just can't seem to exclude functions (I'm adding  `Function` to StopTypes). If you have a ``Date`` it includes all methods, for instance.

Comment: Have you tried including Date to StopTypes. Im on mobile currently. Will adapt it to functilns when I get a chance

Comment: oh right that works perfectly. Im curious of how to exclude functions if you have the time, e.g. I tried `| ((...args: any) => any)` but doesn't pick an entry of `fn: (...args: any) => any;` (or any other)

Comment: I will check later

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEgGOm) work?

Comment: Yes, all is working perfectly in my tests. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, will write the answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm:

- If `T` is some type that we don't want to go deeper with return `''`
- Else if `T` is an array invoke the type for the elements of the `T`
- Else map through the string keys of the `T`, where `K` is the key of `T`:

  - If `T[K]` is some type that we don't want to go deeper with return `K`
  - Else If `T[K]` is some type that we want to ignore, return `never`
  - Else return a union of `K` with a recursive check of the `T[K]`, with prefix of `${K}.` (assuming that at this step we only work with objects)
- Get the values of the mapped type

Implementation:

First, types that we want to stop on, mostly primitives:

```
type StopTypes = number | string | boolean | symbol | bigint | Date;
```

Types to ignore:

```
type ExcludedTypes = (...args: any[]) => any;
```

Type that will allow us to create `.` notation. If the second argument is an empty string, returns the first one without a trailing `.`:

```
type Dot<T extends string, U extends string> = '' extends U ? T : `${T}.${U}`;
```

```
type GetKeys<T> = T extends StopTypes
    ? ''
    : T extends readonly unknown[]
    ? GetKeys<T[number]>
    : {
        [K in keyof T & string]: T[K] extends StopTypes
        ? K
        : T[K] extends ExcludedTypes
        ? never
        : K | Dot<K, GetKeys<T[K]>>;
    }[keyof T & string];
```

We use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type of array type elements and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map through the keys of an object

Testing:

```
type Pack = {
    name: string;
    items: string[];
};

interface Params {
    name: string;
    items: string[];
    pack: Pack;
    packs: Pack[];
    fn: (...args: any) => any;
    nested1: {
        nested2: {
            nested3: string;
        }[];
    };
}
// "name" | "items" | "pack" | "packs" | "nested1" | "pack.name" | "pack.items" | "packs.name" | "packs.items" | "nested1.nested2" | "nested1.nested2.nested3"
type ParamKeys = GetKeys<Params>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9sAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooBVNTHAo0iygPigF4oByPoyx5CDAPxRUALigADACQBvZAF8AdErorZAbgCwAKEOhIUAAoBDAMYBrHlEWGozqNgsBbCDOLkq+gy5QZFju+N5sVADaALr+Kv6GFFgkAGbW0JYkHoSOAS5unuG+lP6BwRChRewxpS5g1jYylra1zvW2YeYNNU4uKdgyABRqIxYklJ0W2CAAlDxcUyCtrhDEELgAjDK5gYHYq1i4AEzbvbu7+2u4AMxVfme7Kj15zvGGKobG4NAAysBwYGQ30IvGwAFd3AAjCAkKAAH1YxXhUEhcDgABsIFNkfgQFCMcjIWRKElkTALFgEgYTNAAKLoKzosG4dZAyAgqDDUbjSbTGJzbgLaZUmlQADiEGAAGkICB8CguLxUBhhCw-gC2asHhIBA8ZMqmCIoCQsbg4Nh0SAoGDsDZsHAAO7YGLa8WSmVylCRcFQmHRDh6hwPQKRKVBbBQGyyuApSRQABkiPY0X1oeiQmYhHVgOBwZcEileecqal6ZVmag9MZzNZuZeuwk+wAbjCi1AZGGEfAkFLaBLpbL5cg0xwOMsnlGQDG44mfMmRd8ull3B6Of3V4hMtkx1AAPS7qAAIgKEEPyMP5VCZ4Rh-aNmvR7v+Afx4O6w2L7vahPn4aakvz7nk+34eKeQENPg-4hIBN6XIcGzfm+xwvnB76IVcRzoYc1yHoYQA)